# Autoresizing issue some from XIB and some using programatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, autoresize

I have developed screen using XIB (Auto resizing) and Xcode 6. In this some UI is dynamic, so programmatically added the UI to the screen. The UI is looking good in 3.5 and 4 inch simulators

The code for dynamically adding UI is

```
-(void)addContenttoScrollview{

    ypostion=190;
    CGRect lframe = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;

    for (int i=0; i<[[[CalculateDataGetter sharedInstance]ChemicalListArray] count]; i++) {
        UIView *contentview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, ypostion, lframe.size.width-35, 24)];
       [self.calculateScrollView addSubview:contentview];
        contentview.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0 green:255.0 blue:255.0 alpha:0.4];
        contentview.layer.borderColor = AgroClinic_Border_COLOR.CGColor;
        contentview.layer.borderWidth =1.5;
        contentview.tag=111;
        ypostion=ypostion+24+10;

        UILabel *chemicalFormulaLbl = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        chemicalFormulaLbl.font = FONT_HELVETICANEUE(14);
        chemicalFormulaLbl.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        chemicalFormulaLbl.numberOfLines=0;
        chemicalFormulaLbl.textColor = AgroClinic_Border_COLOR;
        chemicalFormulaLbl.backgroundColor=CLEAR_COLOR;
        chemicalFormulaLbl.frame= CGRectMake(10, 2, 120, 20);
        chemicalFormulaLbl.text = [[[[CalculateDataGetter sharedInstance]ChemicalListArray] objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"FORMULA"];
        [contentview addSubview:chemicalFormulaLbl];
        chemicalFormulaLbl=nil;

        UILabel *valueLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        valueLabel.font = FONT_HELVETICANEUE(14);
        valueLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        valueLabel.numberOfLines=0;
        valueLabel.textColor = AgroClinic_Border_COLOR;
        valueLabel.backgroundColor=CLEAR_COLOR;
        valueLabel.frame= CGRectMake(200, 2, 120, 20);
        valueLabel.text = [[[[CalculateDataGetter sharedInstance]ChemicalListArray] objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"PESTQUANTITY"];
        valueLabel.tag=i;
        [contentview addSubview:valueLabel];
        valueLabel=nil;
    }
    [self.calculateScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(lframe.size.width,ypostion+40)];
}
```

[image]
[image]

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this Calculate the UI from XIB view height and set the Y position to the below dynamic view.

Comment: but heights of the ui added programatically should be increased when the superview content increased